# D3.js Dijkstra path finder

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, dijkstra, directions

I'd like to create a d3 map path finder by geoJSON paths.

```
g.selectAll("path")
  .data(geojson.features)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "streets")
    .attr("id", function(d){return d.properties.name;})
    .attr("d", path)
        .on("mouseover", function(){text.text(this.id);})
        .on("mouseout", function(){text.text("");});
```

Is it possible to use Dijkstra algorithm to find the best path between 2 points on map?
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mCdU4/1/) is my test map.

I've found a working path finder in d3 [here](http://www.carto.net/svg/dijkstra_shortest_path_demo/)

First step I have to save path connections am I right?
How fast it would be?

Thank you for your help!